# In laravel 5.0 we use bcrypt , so is bcrypt actually contains salt hashing ? if not how to add salt to the normal authentication method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, salt, bcrypt

This is the code to create the password using the bcrypt .how to add salt ?

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) does add a salt.

From the Wikipedia article:

> Besides incorporating a salt to protect against rainbow table attacks, bcrypt is an adaptive function: over time, the iteration count can be increased to make it slower, so it remains resistant to brute-force search attacks even with increasing computation power.

Comment: so if i was asked to add salt to the user password , should i add the salt or not ?

Comment: Just use bcrypt, it adds the salt, the output contains the salt, iteration count and hash. Check the bcrypt link in the answer for more information.